# Return Object when not in enum

Tags: java, parsing, jakarta-ee, enums

## Use case

If the error code is not contained in the enum, return a new `Ausloesungsart`, with the parsed error code of type `UNDEFINED`

## Scenario

I've got some predefined enums.

```
 UNDEFINED(-1),
 FIS(0),
 MANUELL(1)
```

If the error code `-1,0,1` is not in the message received, I want to have this message on the frontend
`<NUMBER> = Unknown`. The enum is of type `Ausloesungsart`, which will be set by

```
public Ausloesung(Ausloesungsart ausloesungsart) {
    setAusloesungsart(ausloesungsart);
}
```

and this is called by the message parser

```
        Ausloesung ausloesung = new Ausloesung(Ausloesungsart.fromIdentifier(header.getReleaseType()));
```

The mapping is here:

```
public static Ausloesungsart fromIdentifier(Integer code) {

        if (enumsByIdentifier.containsKey(code)) {
            return enumsByIdentifier.get(code);
        } else {
            return Ausloesungsart.UNDEFINED;
        }
    }
```

In `Ausloesung`

```
@Type(type = "GenericEnumUserType", parameters = {
@Parameter(name = "enumClass", value = "Ausloesungsart"),
@Parameter(name = "identifierMethod", value = "toIdentifier"),
@Parameter(name = "valueOfMethod", value = "fromIdentifier") })
private Ausloesungsart ausloesungsart;
```

Since enums are final and can't be changed I don't know how I can solve this problem. I need to return a `Ausloesung` in the parsing, which currently expects an `Ausloesungsart`.

**Properties**:

```
# Ausloesungsart
UNDEFINED= {0} \= Unbekannt
FIS=0 \= FIS
MANUELL=1 \= Manuell
```

**xhtml**:

```
<h:outputFormat id="tests1" value="#{res.meldungsList_ausloesungsArt}" 
                          rendered="#{meldungList.meldung.ausloesung.ausloesungsart.identifier == -1}"
                                        style="white-space: nowrap">
                                        <f:param value="#{meldungList.meldung.ausloesung.ausloesungsart}" />
                                        <f:param value="#{meldungList.meldung.ausloesung.ausloesungsart.identifier}" />

                                    </h:outputFormat>

                                    <h:outputFormat id="tests2" value="#{meldungList.meldung.ausloesung.ausloesungsart}" 
                          rendered="#{meldungList.meldung.ausloesung.ausloesungsart.identifier != -1}"
                                        style="white-space: nowrap">
                                    </h:outputFormat>
```

## Problem

the `fromIdentifier` Method is causing the problem. it MUST (architectural) return a Ausloesungsart, but on the other hand I have to dynamically create an Ausloesungsart (which is enum) if it's not contained in the list!

## Update:

Fixed it with a wrapper class.
`class AusloesungsArtWithValues`

Comment: What is the Problem with your code

Comment: I always get `-1 = Undefined`, no matter what the parsed error code is.
I know that currently I always return undefined, which is -1. but that's the problem. I want to return `<CODE> = Unknown`, if it's not in the list!

I tried to add elements to the list, but the mapping would always be to UNDEFINED, which is `-1`. I would need to "instantiate" a new enum at runtime, but this isn't working...

Comment: can you please post and [MCVE]

Comment: Hope this clarifies it. @Jens

Answer (score 0):

Will this implementation of your enum work for you.

```
public class Test3 {
    static enum Ausloesungsart{
        UNDEFINED(-1),
        FIS(0),
        MANUELL(1);
        Ausloesungsart(Integer i){

        }
        public static Ausloesungsart fromIdentifier(Integer i) {
            switch(i) {
                case 0: return FIS;
                case 1: return MANUELL;
                case -1:return UNDEFINED;
            }
            return UNDEFINED;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer input = 0;
        Ausloesungsart enumval = Ausloesungsart.fromIdentifier(input);
        System.out.println(enumval);
    }   
}
```

The enum itself handles any values that are invalid and returns the UNDEFINED version.

Comment: It will always return -1, so sadly no

Comment: No it won't, I tried running this above code. For 1 and 0 it returns corresponding values. For -1 or any other value, it returns UNDEFINED. Isn't that what you want?